# Is it possible to define a label using contents of another label in NASM?

Tags: macos, assembly, label, nasm, x86-64

Consider the following code:

```
    section .data
bar:        db 'bar'        ; label bar
foo_bar:    db 'foo', bar   ; label foo_bar
```

The above code when assembled using NADM under Mac OS X will give the following error:

```
error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses
```

I know that labels refer to some absolute address in the memory, does this mean I need to calculate the absolute 64-bit address of bar? or perhaps I should calculate the relative address of bar? What's going wrong here? Or if I'm using a wrong approach, then how two create a label using contents of another label.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.10. I have a core i5 m540 Intel CPU. I use NASM version 2.11.06.

Comment: Yes, you need relative address because macos requires position independent code by default.

Comment: How Do I calculate the relative address then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your problem statement "create a label using contents of another label" and from your example, it looks like you are trying to combine character strings. If that's what you are trying to do, this can be done as below:

```
foo_bar: db 'foo'
bar:     db 'bar'
```

Note the ordering, it's important. The labels are just address references. So, the above declaration will allocate the string `'foobar'` at some location and label it as `foo_bar`. 
You can assess `"foobar"` at location `foo_bar` and only the `'bar'` at location `bar`.

In your example case, you are not using any kind of string terminators (e.g. 0x0, '$' etc.). So this should work 'O.K.'. But most probably you would want to use the individual parts as well. In such case, additional information to tell the strings apart (like number of characters to read, some separator character etc.) will be needed.

Hope, that this solves your problem. If you need any clarification or you think I misunderstood you problem, please comment with additional information.